# how can we store php variables in jquery variables in jquery part

Tags: php, jquery, variables

```
$('#b').bind('click',function(){
                alert('hii');
                var slide_start=slider_content.indexOf(0);
                if(slide_start==2)
                {
                    $('#reg_rem_form').hide();
                }
        var show=1+slide_start;
        var show_first='#'+show;

        **var value_to_insert=<?php  echo $value;?  >=$(show_first).val();**
                <?php

                        /*
                            1. Date of birth
                            2. gender
                            3. Unvi1
                            4. Unvi2
                            5. highest degree unvi1
                            6. highest degree unvi2
                            7. Year of passing unvi1
                            8. Year of passing unvi2
                            9. Current working
                            10. Work experience
                        */


                ?>
```

Just as we store php variables in jquery variables , same thing but in reverse i want to store jquery variables in php variables ???
The highlighted part is the main line.
how to do that , above code giving me the error ===  missing ";" before statement.

Is this right way to do this
    **=$('#bold').val();**

Comment: PHP is run on the server side before any data is sent to the client. The JavaScript code (which jquery is part of) runs on the client side, after the PHP has already finished running. If you provide more info as to what you're actually trying to accomplish, we might be able to suggest alternative ways to go about doing what you want.

Comment: @Kitsune  - Javascript is for the client - but each document is processed by and for the most part 'built' by PHP before it is sent to the client, often including javascript

Comment: @ClosetGeek Yes, which is why "storing" PHP variables in JavaScript variables is perfectly possible, while the reverse doesn't really make sense. Depending on what the OP is actually wanting to do, (s)he might be able to accomplish their goals by an AJAX request, restructuring the code (PHP and/or JS), or doing part of the PHP portion in JavaScript. Based on just the snippet, an AJAX request seems like it would be the best route.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is to use a hidden elements.

```
<input type="hidden" name="store" id="store"/>
```

On Php side

```
<input type="hidden" 
   name="store" 
   value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($variable); ?>">
```

Then on jquery side

```
var jqueryVar = $('#store).val();
```

Answer (score 0):

Checkout JSON (JavaScript Object Notation)

```
http://php.net/manual/en/book.json.php
```

Converting a PHP array to javascript

```
<?php

$php_array = array(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9);
$js = "var javascript_array = eval('(' + ".json_encode($php_array)." + ')');

?>
```